# How to use definitely typed files in node/express project

Tags: node.js, express, angular, mean-stack, typescript-typings

I started with tsd and later typings that we have to install from these sources and provide reference in the server file, but it now we can get declaration files with @types/filename, I don't know why we moved from tsd and typings and now we are at @types.

How can I use these declaration files into my mean project, I have no idea how can I import or what to do to make it functional and get intelligence and type checking.

I have 2 folders in my project, server and client, the client have angular and all frontend stuff, and the server folder(about node) has package.json, server.ts, node_modules and tsconfig files, here is tsconfig file and server.ts: its throwing error can not find module @types/express

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "typeRoots" : ["./node_modules/@types"],
    "moduleResolution": "node"
}
}

import * as express from "@types/express";
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

This is package.json:

```
{
"name": "server",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "quiz application backend",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"@types/express": "^4.0.34",
"express": "^4.14.0"
}
}
```

Comment: which typescript version? please provide some code: tsconfig, server.ts?

Comment: I didnt included in server.ts because im not getting any intellisense, im including tsconfig in few seconds

Comment: included tsconfig

Comment: I can just guess, but try: `"moduleResolution": "node"`

Comment: also if i forget about the intelisense and copy paste basic server of express and start through node server.js, error is thrown can not find module @types/express,

Comment: you were telling about module loader, is it necessary?

Comment: @lenny what is typeroot btw in tsconfig

Comment: check [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) for explanation. why are you importing "@types/express"? change it to "express".

Comment: it gives red line under express, if im not doing @types/express

Comment: I cannot help you, if you don't give more detailed info about what you did and how your setup looks like (package.json etc.)

Comment: included package.json, actually appllication is running but im not getting intellisense also when i compile the red line under express in import line disappear, but as soon as i start typing the red line reemerges under express at import line, im using vs code IDE

Comment: file structure is: there is only one folder node_modules and all files at the root like package.json, tsconfig and server.ts file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With TypeScript 2 you just need to install the typings via **npm**:

```
npm install @types/lodash --save
```

And start using it in your **ts** file:

```
import * as _ from "lodash";
_.padStart("Hello TypeScript!", 20, " ");
```

Intellisense etc. will work, no need for the old `/// <reference path="..." />` syntax.

Comment: I did it for express like this npm install @types/express it created @types folder in node_module and it has typed file index.d.ts and dependent files, now when im importing like this import * as express from "@types/express";
    var app = express(); its not giving me any intelisence

Comment: you can try to add this to your `tsconfig.json` compilerOptions: `"typeRoots" : ["./node_modules/@types"]`

Comment: its still not giving intelisence, the app variable is of any type

Comment: strange, I just tried it in my app and it worked. what module loader are you using? what typescript version?

Comment: No any module loader im just importing :D

Comment: Im just importing with as ES module system

Comment: Actualy in my previous project that was over year ago, i just refrenced tsd and start working, yes i had module loader in angular(systemjs) but no one on node side,

Comment: Do we need module loader?

Comment: You can edit your question and add some more info about your project setup?